# How to perform validation against dB before NHibernate update

Tags: nhibernate, sharp-architecture

The following scenario is, I would say quite common and although I know one way of resolving it but it lack elegance.

The example I'm giving is based upon https://github.com/sharparchitecture/Sharp-Architecture-Cookbook.

The application I'm coding is an ASP.NET MVC application and has to support multiple users working on the same object.

The following scenario is an edge case but nevertheless a valid one.

Say you have two users working on the same object and whether the dB row can be updated depends upon the value of a particular field. To make it more concrete, let's say you have a Product and to keep things simple, this Product has "Name" and "QuantityInStock" fields.

Say that initially, there are 10 items of the Product and User1 and User2 want to buy this product. When both users are presented the initial form they are told that there are 10 of these items in stock. Now User1 buys all 10 items while User2 goes to have a coffee. So User1's transaction goes through no problem.

Then User2 comes back after his coffee in the belief that there are still 10 items in stock. So he tries to buy 1 but he must be prevented from doing so since there are no items in stock.

So this problem can be solved by using ASP.NET DataAnnotations validation and this will catch the majority of cases. However, in our edge case, say that User1 and User2 perform the same operation but within a fraction of a second such that when User2 submits the form, it passes the ASP.NET Validation but by the time it gets to the persistence layer, the QuantityInStock is 0.

The solution to this is to perform the validation at the latest moment as possible i.e. just before calling the Update method.

Now for some code.

```
public ProductModel CreateOrUpdate(ProductModel productModel)
{
    var currentProductModel = Get(productModel.Id);

    var currentQuantityInStock = currentProductModel.QuantityInStock;


    if(currentProductModel.QuantityInStock !=0 && productModel.QuantityInStock >= currentQuantityInStock )
    {
        currentProductModel.QuantityInStock= productModel.QuantityInStock;
        currentProductModel.Name = productModel.Name;

        this.productModelRepository.SaveOrUpdate( currentProductModel );
        return productModel;
    }
    else
    {
        //Raise an exception
    }
}
```

Now, the fact that I'm calling:

```
 var currentProductModel = Get(productModel.Id);
```

means that if I were to just do this:

```
 this.productModelRepository.SaveOrUpdate( productModel );
```

would cause an exception:

> a different object with the same identifier value was already associated with the session: 1

Hence, I have to copy all of the values from productModel to currentProductModel. It's fine when using something like Automapper but still kind of feels wrong to me in the sense that I feel I should just be able to save productModel as is without having to transfer the data from one object to another.

Moreover, having to do the same validation twice, once using DataAnnotation and another time just before updating violates the DRY principle.

The point is that I feel like I'm missing a trick but don't quite know where to start and what to investigate.

This to me is a simple problem but coming up with a nice elegant solution is something else. So the question is how have you dealt with this simple case in the past? Am I overthinking this?

Answer (score 0):

have you tried optimistic Locking with Version?

```
// Fluent mapping
public EntitiyMap()
{
    OptimisticLock.All();   // all properties musn't be changed in db when saving
    // or
    OptimisticLock.Dirty();   // only dirty properties musn't be changed in db when saving
}


//
public ProductModel CreateOrUpdate(ProductModel productModel)
{
    try
    {
        // productModel is already validated and updated
        this.productModelRepository.SaveOrUpdate( productModel );

        return productModel;
    }
    catch (StaleObjectException)
    {
        // somebody changed the object in database after we have read it
        // Raise an exception or whatever
    }
}
```

Update: i handled such things in another way

```
public void BuySomething(ProductModel productModel, int amount)
{
    int tries = 5;
    bool success = false;
    while(!success && tries > 0)
    {
        if (productModel.QuantityInStock <= amount)
        {
            //Raise an exception
        }

        productModel.QuantityInStock - amount;
        try
        {
            this.productModelRepository.SaveOrUpdate( productModel );
        }
        catch (StaleObjectException)
        {
            // somebody changed the object in database after we have read it
            this.productModelRepository.Refresh(productModel);
            tries--;
        }
    }
    if (tries <= 0)
    {
        // Raise an exception or whatever
    }
}
```

zero extra roundtrips if nobody changed it in between, and guaranteed serialisation of the transactions

Comment: Yes this works of course. However, the scenario could be that User1 buys 5 while User2 buys 1 and we don't want to trigger the StaleObjectException in that case.

Comment: why not, if you dont trigger staleobject you will have Quantity 5 or 9 in db but there should actually be 4, no?

Comment: Maybe my code for "CreateOrUpdate" wasn't clear enough. Please see the update in the "if" condition for the update to be applied. Imagine a web site with a large number of transactions. Users won't be too happy to resubmit their order if there are items in stock but the StaleObjectException gets triggered.